# How to serialize Xml Date only from DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, serialization, xml-serialization

I've the following simple class;

```
Birthdays
{
  public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I then serialise my object to Xml using;

```
try
{
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ms.Position = 0;
        xmlDoc.Load(ms);
        return xmlDoc;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ....
}
```

The problem I have is that when the Xml is returned the `DateOfBirth` format is like `2012-11-14T00:00:00` and not `2012-11-14`.

How can I override it so that I'm only returning the date part ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use the [`XmlElementAttribute.DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and specify [`date`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp).

```
public class Birthdays
{
  [XmlElement(DataType="date")]
  public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Using this outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Birthdays xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DateOfBirth>2013-11-14</DateOfBirth>
  <Name>John Smith</Name>
</Birthdays>
```

Another option is to use a `string` property just for serialization (backed by a `DateTime` property you use), as at [Force XmlSerializer to serialize DateTime as 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534525/force-xmlserializer-to-serialize-datetime-as-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss) (this is needed for `DataContractSerializer`, where the `xs:date` type is not as well-supported)

Comment: better than my answer I have to admit :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this example out:

```
        string date = "2012-11-14T00:00:00";

        string result = DateTime.Parse(date).ToShortDateString();

        //or....

        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();

        dateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
        //now its only use dateTime.Date
```

Comment: (second part:) Would cut off any existing time, but still "dateTime" has the 00:00 Time. Would not change a thing.

Comment: thats why i commented use datetime.Date.

Comment: But still: The xml would look just like before

Comment: if the problem is in wants serialized then not mine not yours but tim S.(for a single property result i mean).my answer is to not rewrite the class(although it is the best solution),and just "get" the desired formatt.

Comment: Helped me get there for XElement save of just the date, thanks.