# XmlSerializer not deserializing DateTime

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, serialization

I have an XML document I'm deserializing using `XmlSerializer`. The other properties on the document work just fine, but there is one element in particular that isn't working:

```
<StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
```

This is defined in C# in a POCO as:

```
[XmlElement("StartDate")]
private DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

When I deserialize the document, `StartDate` is `01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM`. I thought the standard XML date/time format was `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`? So why is this not deserializing correctly?

**Note:** I do not have control over the XML document I'm deserializing. It's coming from a third-party system.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3534625/2974754) should help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the access modifier from `private` to `public`:

```
[XmlElement("StartDate")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

[XmlSerializer can only serialize public fields and properties.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh wow, how did I miss that? All my other properties were public. Stupid mistake! Thanks!