# Serialized XML Date Time value is not correct

Tags: c#, xml

I have an issue with Serializing XML. I have an object with a DateTime property where the millisecond value is 990. However when I view the outputted string it is showing like this...

```
<ReadingsDateTime>2016-07-04T10:10:00.99Z</ReadingsDateTime>
```

The code used to convert this to xml is below, what is going on, I can not find a reason that this is happening.

```
string xml;

try
{    
    var serializer = new XmlSerializerFactory().CreateSerializer(typeof(T), xmlNamespace);

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = false,
            NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates,
            CloseOutput = false,
            WriteEndDocumentOnClose = true,
        };

        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings))
        {
            serializer?.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
        }

        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using (var steamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
        {
            xml = steamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Unable to convert to XML from an object", ex);
}

return xml;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.990 is the same as .99, its a fractional number so the last 0 digit is dropped. Digits have importance starting from the left hand side and going to the right. Example:

- 1.0000 is the same value as 1
- 2.94 is the same value as 2.940 or 2.9400 or 2.94000.

The serializer just removes the trailing 0 digits. If you want to always capture any trailing 0 digits (not sure why you would) you can add a custom string property and specify the exact output to be serialized and read in there and ignore the DateTime property, see this previous [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3534625/1260204) as example.

Comment: Is this a .Net specific 'thing'. The xml is created to post to an Api. If that system was Java would they treat the millisecond part as a fractional number as well?

Comment: @Hyder - its not anything specific to .net but that is just how the `XmlSerializer` serializes the fractionalal part of the millisecond value which makes sense as the trailing `0`s do not add anything of value. The result could be different depending on the serializer user and who wrote it but the string/serialized value should be able to be parsed/deserialized back to the same DateTime value either way. As far as Java I would guess it was the same but I do not know Java so could not say for sure.