# How to convert to a longDateString in the object setter?

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I have a class with Getter and Setter:

```
public class MyClassEntity
{
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }    
}

public MyClassEntity MyData { get; set; }
```

That class is serialized from xml generated by Stored Procedure.
This is an XML portion that is serialized to MyData class

```
  <MyData>
    <MyDate>2017-03-29</MyDate>
  </MyData>
```

I'm looking for the solution to return MyDate.ToLongDateString() to my model.

I tried a couple of things but that did not help much.

I was trying to declare a string and assign a `value.ToLongDateString()`
I could not convert `value` to what I need.

How can I do that?

Comment: what are the ouput that you've seen so far ?

Comment: I don't understand. A `DateTime` has no format. I don't understand why calling `MyDate.ToString("your format here");` doesn't suffice?

Comment: What I need to do is return value converted to LongDateString

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force XmlSerializer to serialize DateTime as 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534525/force-xmlserializer-to-serialize-datetime-as-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)