# DateTime Format after Serialization with BulkCopy

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, serialization

I have a problem after deserializing an XML response. The Date is always set to {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}.

Here is my DTO class definition:

```
    [XmlElement]
    public System.DateTime Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
```

The problem is the formatting of the received XML from the server.  I used a DB first approach and populated my objects from the existing DB so the class was automatically constructed with DateTime as the property type.  The SQL data type is "Date".  I don't have a problem when manually importing records in an excel spreadsheet, but the purpose of this program is to automate the procedure using the XML response.

An example response looks like this:

```
<root><i Other_Attributes="" Date_of_Birth="10/21/1999" More_Attributes="" /></root>
```

I've seen the suggestions like the one below:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SomeDate")]
    public string SomeDateString
    {
        get { return this.SomeDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); }
        set { this.SomeDate = DateTime.Parse(value); }
    }
}
```

But this results in my datatable having too many columns (the extra string value) and the BulkCopy fails.

**EDIT:**
The reason my conversion to a BulkCopy as DataTable was failing was because I was either mapping too many columns, or using the wrong accessor method.  I was able to solve by changing my DTO to the following:

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Date_of_Birth")]
    public string Date_of_Birth_String
    {
        get { return this.Date_of_Birth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); }
        set { this.Date_of_Birth = DateTime.Parse(value); }
    }
```

Then I had to change my method that converts my deserialized object to a DataTable adding the string value to the DateTime row like so:

```
    public static DataTable AsDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        var table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        {
            if( prop.Name == "Date_of_Birth_String")
            {
                continue;
            }
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        }
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            {
                if (prop.Name == "Date_of_Birth_String")
                {
                    row["Date_of_Birth"] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    continue;
                }
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
```

Comment: The question is unclear to me. You try to automate import of records from DB on Sql Server to MS Excel spreadsheet? Could you show the code you are using so far and which doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `XmlSerializer` [does not support customized formats for `DateTime` properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3534525/3744182), so you will need a surrogate `string` property to parse and format your `DateTime` in the required format.

However, in your XML the `Date_Of_Birth` is an [attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-attr) rather than a child [element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-element) so you will need to mark the surrogate property with [`[XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Date_of_Birth")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="i")]
public class I 
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }      

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Other_Attributes")]
    public string Other_Attributes { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Date_of_Birth")]
    public string Date_of_Birth 
    { 
        get { return this.SomeDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); }
        set { this.SomeDate = DateTime.Parse(value); }          
    }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="More_Attributes")]
    public string More_Attributes { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="root")]
public class Root {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="i")]
    public I I { get; set; }
}
```

Here I used https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ to automatically generate classes for your XML then modified the `Date_of_Birth` property to make use of the underlying `DateTime SomeDate` property.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7E5JXw) showing that your XML string can be deserialized and re-serialized to:

```
<root>
  <i Other_Attributes="" Date_of_Birth="1999-10-21 00:00:00" More_Attributes="" />
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!