# XmlSerializer with Specified pattern not working

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

We're trying to consume a web service (Soap) and have generated an adapter for the schema using SvcUtil.exe.  We have a field

> recurrenceCount

which should not be provided unless it has a value and so we have added a property

> recurrenceCountSpecified

as according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) .  Even though recurrenceCountSpecified is false, the field recurrenceCount property is still specified in the outgoing xml.

What are we doing wrong ?

Adapter code :

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel","3.0.0.0")]  [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://sas.elluminate.com/", ConfigurationName ="SASDefaultAdapterV2Port")] 
public interface SASDefaultAdapterV2Port 
{
     [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://sas.elluminate.com/setSession",ReplyAction = "*")]      
     [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(sas.elluminate.com.ErrorResponse), Action = "http://sas.elluminate.com/setSession", Name="ErrorResponse")] 
     [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
     sessionResponseCollection setSession(setSessionRequest request); 
}
```

The modified class is :

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel","3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="setSession", WrapperNamespace = "http://sas.elluminate.com/",IsWrapped = true)]
public partial class setSessionRequest
{

     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]       
     public bool recurrenceCountSpecified;

     [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://sas.elluminate.com/", Order = 19)]
     public int recurrenceCount;

}
```

Comment: See also question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009895/svcutil-exe-proxy-generated-not-allowing-for-nullable-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're attempting to use (xxxSpecified properties) does not apply if you're using a MessageContract. It applies only to the XmlSerializer. You have correctly specified that XmlSerializer should be used for the operation. However, because you have also specified that MessageContracts are to be used, the XmlSerializer only kicks in at the next level of serialization - i.e. when serializing each message member.